# How to print varying fields from input lines in Unix

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I am new to KSH scripting and need to know where am I making a mistake..I need to print field 1 and field 2 from abc.dat file.

```
#!/bin/ksh

f="abc.dat"
l=`sed '1d;$d' $f|wc -l`
l1=2
while ( $l1 -lt $l ) 
do
   echo 'First Field= '`sed -n "${l1}p" $f|cut -d"|" -f1` ', then second field= ' `sed -n "${l1}p" $f|cut -d"|" -f2`
   (( l1++ ))
done
```

sorry.. i have a file with below data,

```
Allan|2000|5000
Smith|5000|3000
Roy|1000|3000
```

i need below output with KSH scripting,

```
first field=Allan, then 2nd field=2000
first field=Smith, then 2nd field=3000
```

and so on....

thank you
Example input.txt

```
Test1|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
Test2|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
Test3|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
Sometext|b|c|d|e|f|g
Test5|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
Test6|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
```

Output:

```
First field=Test1, then 2nd field=Field: 1
First field=Test2, then 2nd field=Field: 2
First field=Test3, then 2nd field=Field: 3
First field=Sometext, then 2nd field=Field: e
First field=Test5, then 2nd field=Field: 5
First field=Test6, then 2nd field=Field: 6
```

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Comment: sorry Pedro...i have a file

Comment: I understood that already...

Comment: ksh doesn't have some equivalent of bash's `read`? Because that's how you should be doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "first field=%s, then 2nd field=%s\n", $1, $(NR+1) }' input.txt
```

- `awk` splits each input line into fields by `|` (`-F'|'`).
- `printf` then prints the format string with each input line's 1st field (`$1`) and the *n*-th field (`$(NR+1)`), where *n* is calculated as the number of the current input row (`NR`) + 1.

Apart from being simpler, this `awk` solution will generally perform much better than a solution that loops in *shell* code - loops in shell code are best avoided, especially when external utilities are called in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would point you at Awk:

```
cat data_file | awk -F\| '{print "First field" $1 ", then 2nd field =" $2}'
```

This will set the field separator for Awk to be the pipe symbol and effectively split the lines for you.  Awk is definitely a tool to get to know a bit about.  Honestly, many of the ways that people try to use Sed are way better suited to Awk. :)

Comment: This works for the first line. The second line needs $3, the third needs $4.
That's why `while IFS="|" read field1 field2` won't work either.

Comment: I did not take that away from your question.  You may want to edit it.  You state "first field, second field, first field, second field."

Comment: I edited the question, since I missed it too the first time I read the question. The example `first field=Smith, then 2nd field=3000` gave me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

When the fields do not have spaces, you can use as solution with cut:

```
lastfield=2
while read -r line; do
   printf "First field=%s, second field=%s\n" $(echo ${line}|cut -d"|" -f1,${lastfield} | sed 's/|/ /')
   (( lastfield = lastfield + 1 ))
done < input.txt
```